# Line integrals in space interpretation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I realize that the line integral $$\int_Cf(x,y)ds$$ can represent the area under the function f along the curve $C$ but what does it represent in 3D?

For instance if the curve was a helix increasing its height along the Z axis can you say that $$\int_Cf(x,y,z)ds$$ can represent some sort of area?

Thanks!

Comment: It's the same: it is just the surface area between the graph of the function (in a 4D space $(x,y,z,t)$) and the 3d-plane $\{t=0\}$, that is "above" the curve.

Comment: The use of the double integral notation here doesn't make sense to me. Since you're integrating over a curve, the pull-back of the arclength element with be a multiple of $dt$; you don't need an iterated integral.

Comment: @symplectomorphic you are very correct. What do you mean when you say "pull-back" of the arclength element.

Comment: @Nash: the pullback is formal tool used to define integration in differential geometry; it's how you transform the integral you wrote into one based on a parametrization. You may be interested in the discussion here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99488/the-ds-which-appears-in-an-integral-with-respect-to-arclength-is-not-a-1-form